# Error in the first Anaconda launch

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I've just installed Anaconda 2 with Python 2.7 and during the first Spyder Launch got this error:

> [IPKernelApp] CRITICAL | Bad config encountered during initialization:
>   [IPKernelApp] CRITICAL | Could not decode
>   'C:\Users\\xc5\xe2\xe3\xe5\xed\xe8\xff\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime'
>   for unicode trait 'connection_dir' of an IPKernelApp instance.

How can I fix this?
Please, help, i need it for online course and it has deadlines.

Comment: I have the same problem with a newly installed Anaconda environment. Were you able to fix this issue? Thx!